# C++ pairs and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, std-pair

I don't know what can I do to make this work in C++.

The intend is:

```
pair<int, int> foo() {
  if(cond) {
    return std::make_pair(1,2);
  }
  return NULL; //error: no viable conversion from 'long' to 'pair<int, int>
}
void boo() {
  pair<int, int> p = foo();
  if (p == NULL) { //error: comparison between NULL and non-pointer ('int, int' and NULL)
    // doA
  } else {
    int a = p.first;
    int b = p.second;
    // doB
  }
}
```

Since I cannot use return NULL in C++, here is my 2nd try:

```
pair<int, int>* foo() {
  if(cond) {
    return &std::make_pair(1,2); //error: returning address of local temporary object)
  }
  return nullptr;
}
void boo() {
  pair<int, int>* p = foo();
  if (p == nullptr) {
    // doA
  } else {
    int a = p->first;
    int b = p->second;
    // doB
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to be able to return a pair and a null value.

Comment: For starters, [avoid pair](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/158531-stdpair-considered-harmful).

Comment: Use `new` to allocate the pair on the heap.

Comment: @Barmar, No. Just no.

Comment: Why do you want to use NULL?

Comment: Come to think of it, what is `cond`? Could you move the evaluation of `cond` into `boo()`? As it stands, `foo()` is just an unnecessary wrapper around std::make_pair()

Comment: this is just a generalization of the problem, I cannot expose the actual production code.

Comment: What you need is `optional`

Comment: Is this an exceptional condition, or a frequent occurrence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try passing in a pair to foo() by reference, then returning a bool from that function indicating success or failure. Like so:

```
bool foo(pair<int, int>& myPair) {
  if(cond) {
    myPair = std::make_pair(1,2);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
void boo() {
  pair<int, int> myPair;
  if (!foo(myPair)) {
    // doA
  } else {
    int a = myPair.first;
    int b = myPair.second;
    // doB
  }
}
```

Edit: Depending on what you're doing, you should just kill `foo()` if possible and evaluate `cond` within `boo()`

```
void boo() {
  pair<int, int> myPair;
  if (!cond) {
    // doA
  } else {
    myPair = std::make_pair(1,2);
    int a = myPair.first;
    int b = myPair.second;
    // doB
  }
}
```

Comment: edit: as I mentioned before, the code snippet is a generalization of the problem. The production code is much more complex.

Answer (score 11):

You should use an exception:

```
std::pair<int, int> foo() {
    if(cond) {
        return std::make_pair(1,2);
    }
    throw std::logic_error("insert error here");
}
```

and in your `boo` function:

```
try {
    std::pair<int, int> p = foo();
    int a = p.first;
    int b = p.second;
} catch (std::logic_error const& e) {
    // do something
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a67dc37699d4c3b)'s the live example.

---

In alternative you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (since C++14) or `boost::optional`:

```
std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> foo() {
    if(cond) {
        return std::make_pair(1,2);
    }
    return {};
}

std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> p = foo();
if (p) {
    int a = p->first;
    int b = p->second;
} else {
    // do something
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5203000befaf51c)'s a the working example with the boost version.

Comment: I like this solution the most. I do however hate try-catching all the time especially if using sjlj-gcc vs. seh-gcc. `std::optional` is dropped from C++14 no? Other than that, +1 from me.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but I am actually trying to avoid try-catch if it's not an error condition.

Comment: @Jefffrey, optional solution looks awesome, I like it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - it is, but it's slated for release this year in the Library Fundamentals TS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for a `Nullable` type. There's no reason to use dynamic memory. This approach is completely bombastic and unnecessary, but it most fits what you were trying to 'achieve' with your original code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct NullablePair
{
    std::pair<T, U> pair;
    T first  = pair.first;
    U second = pair.second;
    NullablePair(const std::pair<T, U>& other) : pair(other) { }
    NullablePair() { }
    operator std::nullptr_t() const {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
NullablePair<T, U> foo(bool cond) {
  if(cond) {
    return NullablePair<T, U>(std::make_pair(1,2));
  }
  return NullablePair<T, U>();
}

void boo() {
  NullablePair<int, int> p = foo<int, int>(false);
  if (p == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Nullptr.\n";
  } else {
    int a = p.first;
    int b = p.second;
  }
}

int main()
{
    boo();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to maintain the function signature, then you can use pair. So in your return statement in the function foo(), you can return std::make_pair(NULL, NULL).

```
pair<int, int> foo() 
{
    // Initialize cond

    if(cond) 
        return std::make_pair(1,2);
    return std::make_pair(NULL, NULL);
}
```

You can then check if p.first and p.second equal NULL in boo() function